# Forcing belongsTo in add view

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 tables, users, agents, and owners.  An Agent and an Owner will be a type of User and and in my model I've defined $belongsTo() properly in both Agent and Owner.

Everything is working properly in that I can add a User and then go to the the agents or owners route and create a new agent or owner that references that user record.

My question is, what is the official cake way to allow a new agent or owner to be added and a user is automatically created and linked up?  I would like to skip the step of creating a user, and instead just create an agent or an owner and have the user created automatically.

I've read about the relationships here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html and did some searching, but I can't find anything that seems to describe the situation.

Instinctively, I would think that the way to do this was to provide some logic in the add method of the Agents and Owners controller that would create a new User and then modify the view in such a way that the dropdown for a user doesn't show, but is there a more correct way to do this in cake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, what is the official cake way to allow a new agent or
>   owner to be added and a user is automatically created and linked up? I
>   would like to skip the step of creating a user, and instead just
>   create an agent or an owner and have the user created automatically.

Just use [Model::afterSave()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-AclBehavior.html#_afterSave). Check if it is a new record and then just create the associated recrods.